# How do I retrieve data from a distant relationship model in Laravel Eloquent using method chaining?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have Models A, B and C. A hasOne relationship with B and B hasMany relationship with C.

```
//Model Code

class A extends Model
{
    //This relates A and B
    public function relateBC(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\B','aid','aid');
    }
}

class B extends Model
{
    //Inverse relationship with Model A
    public function relateBC(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\A','aid','aid');
    }

    //This relates B and C
    public function relateBC(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\C','bid','bid');
    }
}


class C extends Model
{
    //Inverse relationship with Model B
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\B','bid','bid');
    }
}
```

Below code return data from Model B

```
App\A::find(id)->relateAB()->get();
```

Below code return data from Model C

```
App\B:find(id)->relateBC()->get();
```

The below code throw BadMethodException. Method relateBC() does not exist.

```
App\A::find(id)->relateAB->relateBC()->get();
```

.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$distantRelations = App\A::find($id)->relateAB->relateBC;
```

When accessed as a method (i.e. `->relateAB()`), you get back the [HasOne relationship object](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php) (the object you can call `->get()` on), whereas when accessed as a magic property (i.e. ->relateAB), you get back the model instance (the object you can access relationship `relateBC`) on.

You *could* use the method instead of the magic property, but keep in mind that you are then the one who has to determine the relation type (one vs. many), and call either `->get()` or `->first()` on the underlying query builder respectively:

```php
$distantRelations = App\A::find($id)

    // 'relateAB' is a singular relation,
    // so we'll need to call 'first()'

    ->relateAB()->first() // > App\B

    // 'relateBC' is a 'many' relation,
    // so we'll need to call 'get()'

    ->relateBC()->get();  // > App\C[]|\Illuminate\Support\Collection
```

**`HasOne` calling `first()`**

You can witness `HasOne` calling `first()` for you on the query builder [at this line](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php#L20), executed by accessing the relation as magic property.

**`HasMany` calling `get()`**

You can witness `HasMany` calling `get()` for you on the query builder [at this line](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php#L16), executed by accessing the relation as magic property.

Comment: Tried that, I got a BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::relateAB()'

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code (strip out unnecessary stuff). Include the 3 models and the relevant relation methods. Also some information about you database tables (their names, the names of the primary key columns) would help.

Answer (score 0):

declared primary key of A model and B model in Pivot table i.e. as foreign key of both the tables